# Run fetch only for browser execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am using `fetch` to verify email in browser, so I want to check that if the url is opened in browser then only my `fetch` is executed, otherwise not.

What’s happening now is that the crawlers crawling that page (Let’s say Gmail crawling the verification link) is resulting in auto-verification without human intervention.

I can use `reCaptcha` for it, but if there exists any other solution then it would be great

Comment: Are you sure that actually happens? According to this 2015 article gmail doesn't crawl the links in emails: https://www.stonetemple.com/does-google-sniff-gmail-for-urls/

Comment: @stone yah thts hapenning, i'm not sure with gmail but with other crawlers, i gave gmail as an example

Comment: How can you tell?

Comment: When a bot opens your page, it is not different than it being opened in a browser. However, you can at least create a robots.txt and tell crawlers that you do not want that page to be crawled. When they index that file, they'll most probably leave it alone.